Where does it say the Nachash wanted to kill Adam and Chava?
I have in my notes that the Rokeach says the Nachash wanted to kill Adam and Chava and inherit the whole world.
But now I can't seem to find it inside. Maybe it was a different reishon. Im looking for any reishon or chazal that say the Nachash wanted to kill both Chava and Adam.

See https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%A9_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99#:~:text=%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA%20%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%98%D7%94,%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%97%D7%95%D7%94.

Related: "What was the serpent’s plan?"
